# Does Dodge allow the player to roll saving dex when attacked? Otherwise, when would a saving throw be used?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, saving-throw

New DM here. Hosted a game this weekend for my kids who have never played. (I have never been DM and haven't played for 20+ years.) I am trying to figure out Dodge and saving throws.

Dodge - Only used as an action on a turn, would then allow player to roll saving dex when attacked?

Saving throws - besides like a trap when else would they use these?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, but this question shows little to no research effort. It would be good to read the rules and then explain why you have trouble with this part. Also: taking the [tour] is good!

Comment: @Trish I disagree... The fact that he has two halves of Dodge confused and commingled indicates he did read, but didn't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Does dodge allow a player to do a Dexterity Saving Throw when attacked?**

No, it doesn't. When you use the [Dodge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dodge) action, two things may happen:

1. If you are attacked, the attacker has *disadvantage*.
2. If something happens that causes you to do a Dexterity [saving throw](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#SavingThrows), you have advantage in that saving throw roll.

So using Dodge action don't make you roll a Dexterity saving throw when attacked, but it still make you harder to hit.

**Besides avoiding trap effect, when would you do a Dexterity Saving Throw?**

Mostly when you are subjected to spells that require you to do one. This depends solely on the spell.

Answer (score 17):

### Dodge

The **[Dodge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Dodge)** action is primarily used to avoid attacks. It causes the attacker to have *disadvantage* (roll twice, take the lowest). The dodging character doesn't make any additional rolls against attacks.

**Dodge** also grants the target *advantage* (roll twice, take the highest) on Dexterity saving throws.

Both benefits require the dodging character to see the incoming attack.

### Saves

**[Saving Throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SavingThrows)** are more frequently the result of spellcasting or secondary effects of creature attacks, rather than traps. Some spells use an attack roll made by the caster, while others cause a save by the target. They are used in a context where their effectiveness is not based on effort or skill of the attacker but by failure of the defender.

### Example

Some creatures (e.g. **[Giant Spider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-spider)**) inflict poison with their attacks. While their attack roll determines if the actual attack makes contact, it has no bearing on the effectiveness of the venom. If the conditions are satisfied (target is dodging and can see the attacker), they'd make this attack roll with disadvantage.

If the attack hits, the target makes a Constitution saving throw (aiming to beat the save DC described in the attack) to determine if their body is capable of resisting the effects of the venom. Dodge has no effect here, the attack has already landed.

By contrast, a spell like **[Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)** requires a Dexterity saving throw to reduce damage. A Dodging character would receive advantage on this save, as long as he can see it coming.